# Facebook API: Adding App without authorization

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on first Fb App, when I visit my App , it first shows the Dialog of Goto App [screen shot 1](http://i39.tinypic.com/166knzo.png). When I click GotoApp, it already adds application in [App Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications).Then it shows Permission Dialog, given [here](http://i43.tinypic.com/fcr145.png). Now even if I click Cancel then it does not remove Application at all.

COde snippet is [here](http://pastie.org/3606527)

I don't want to add Application Unless and Untill User ALLOW it.

**I am in Sandbox Mode**

Pls help it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook changed the authentication dialog to include 2 steps, the first for "user and friends permissions" and the second for "extended permissions" (if asked at all). You can read all about it [Auth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/) document.

The permissions your app asks for in the 2nd step (the extended permissions) are optional and the user can choose not to grant some or all of them. There's no way to force a user to grant you all permissions, here's what you can do:

Once the user finished the authentication process check for the permissions he granted the app, you can do it with a simple graph call to: [https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions), this will get you the permissions the app has for that user.
If the user hasn't granted you with all the permissions that you **must** have then you have two options:

1. Show him a page telling him that those permissions are mandatory and that he has to accept them all if he wants to use the app
2. Redirect the user to the auth dialog again, in a loop, until he either accepts all permissions or just gives up and stop trying to use your app.

Just keep in mind that the more permissions you ask for (and insist on), the less users will be inclined to use your app.

Comment: I got this part. Thanks but why it's adding the app even if the user did not authorize it? Does it mean it adds up at first stage before even user click ALLOW button?

Comment: Yes, after the user authorizes the first dialog the application is part of his applications, as I said the 2nd dialog is just to add extra permissions and it is optional.